# Why is there no "encoding" attribute in a string got by "IXMLDocument.SaveToXML" method?

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin

I use `NewXMLDocument()` to produce an XML document of my data.

There is a `SaveToXML()` method to save the document to an XML-formatted string variable.

The problem is that the XML string does not contain an `"encoding"` attribute in the head tag.

But, if we save the XML document to a file with the `SaveToFile()` method, the `"encoding"` attribute will exist in it.

Here is my code:

```
var
  XML: IXMLDocument;
  RootNode, CurNode: IXMLNode;
  XmlString: string;
begin
  XML := NewXMLDocument;
  XML.Encoding := 'utf-8';
  XML.Options := [doNodeAutoIndent];
  RootNode := XML.AddChild('XML');
  CurNode := RootNode.AddChild('List');
  CurNode := CertList.AddChild('Item');
  CurNode.Text := 'bla-bla-bla';
  ...

  XMl.SaveToXML(XmlString);  // <<--- no "encoding" attribute here

  XMl.SaveToFile('my-list.xml');
  XMl := nil;
end;
```

Is there a way to make the `SaveToXML()` method add the `"encoding"` attribute?

Comment: Just from looking at the code, I think that if you declare `XmlString` as `UTF8String` you will have the result you want. not sure, and I can't test right now.

Comment: with `XmlString` as `UTF8String` I got `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` Thanks a lot!

Comment: @kobik Please add comment as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: @Zurab-D makes sense that a UTF-8 "encoding" attribute will not be added to a string that is not actually encoded as UTF-8 to begin with, as `string` is UTF-16 in Delphi 2009+.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the overload method `IXMLDocument.SaveToXML(var XML: UTF8String)`.
That will encode the xml to UTF-8 and add the encoding attribute in the xml header.
Declare your `XmlString` as `UTF8String` to get the desired result.

When you declare `XmlString` as `string` like you did, which is UTF-16 (Unicode) in Delphi 2009+, you actually call `SaveToXML(var XML: DOMString)`. The `DOMString` is defined as `UnicodeString`.
By default, variables declared as type `string` are `UnicodeString`. The output xml is UTF-16 and the encoding attribute is omitted.